# Como organizar páginas com uma tabela em Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte each que retorna todos os registros de clientes dentro de um table, e que funciona perfeitamente:

```
  $.each(data, function(key,item)
  {
    id_cliente = item.id;
    nome_cliente = item.nome;
    data_nascimento_cliente = formataDataSQL(item.data_nascimento);
    telefone_cliente = item.telefone;
    celular_cliente = item.celular;
    cpf_cliente = item.cpf;
    endereco_cliente = item.endereco;
    email_cliente = item.email;

    itemHTML += "<tbody>";
    itemHTML += "<tr>";
    itemHTML += "<td><th><input type='checkbox' value='" +  id_cliente + "' name='verifica_check_box[]' id='verifica_check_box' class='flat'/></th></td>";
    itemHTML += "<td>" + nome_cliente + "</td>";
    itemHTML += "<td>" + data_nascimento_cliente + "</td>";
    itemHTML += "<td>" + telefone_cliente + "</td>";
    itemHTML += "<td>" + celular_cliente + "</td>";
    itemHTML += "<td>" + cpf_cliente  + "</td>";
    itemHTML += "<td>" + endereco_cliente + "</td>";
    itemHTML += "<td>" + email_cliente  + "</td>";
    itemHTML += "</tr>";
    itemHTML += "</tbody>";
  });

  itemHTML += "</table>";
  container_mostra_cliente.html(itemHTML);
}
```

Aqui ele exibe uma tabela normal, mas eu queria que fosse desse jeito: Igual uma paginação, cada DIV vai ter que ter 4 registros. Se tiver 20 registros na tabela ela via ter que ser quebrada em DIVS com 4 informações cada div, exemplo:

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/khpo3k8m/2/

Assim ficaria mais fácil fazer uma paginação.

Como retornar os valores do datatable? Já tentei em ajax e nada!

```
    $('.mostra_clientes .table').DataTable( {
         retrieve: true,
         "processing": true,
         paging: false,
         searching: false,
          "pageLength": 4,
          "ajax": {
          "type"   : "GET",
          "url"    : url_base + "clientes",
        },
        "columns": [
          { "data": "nome" },
          { "data": "data_nascimento" },
          { "data": "telefone" },
          { "data": "celular" },
          { "data": "cpf" },
          { "data": "endereco" },
          { "data": "email" }
        ]
      } );
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

CÓDIGO DO DATATABLE COM DESTROY. NÃO FUNCIONA:

```
 function retorna_cliente()
 {
  var tabela = $('.mostra_clientes .table').DataTable({
  "pageLength": 4,
  "bPaging": "false",
  "bDestroy": "true",
  "ajax": {
    "url": url_base + "clientes",
    "type": "GET",
    "dataSrc": "",
  },
  "columns": [
    {
      "data": function ( data, type, row ) {
        return "<input type='checkbox' value='"+data['id']+"' name='verifica_check_box[]' id='verifica_check_box' class='flat'/>";
      }
    },
    { "data":"nome"},
    { "data":"telefone"},
    { "data":"cpf"},
    { "data":"endereco"},
    { "data":"email"},
  ],
  "bLengthChange": false,
  "bInfo": false,
  "bAutoWidth": false
  });

    tabela.destroy();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Existem diversas formas de você fazer paginação, vou demonstrar uma utilizando [Datatable](https://datatables.net) um plugin para `jquery`.

Ao invés de criar uma variável e montar o `HTML` nela para depois inserir, você pode criar um vetor com os dados e através do plugin atribuir os dados contidos nesse vetor ao seu `HTML`.

[Construindo tabelas com paginação através de dados em um vetor JS](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html)

Deixei também comentado um exemplo com AJAX e JSON

[Ajax sourced data](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)

[Ajax data source (objects)](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/objects.html)

```js
/*
Exemplo com Ajax e JSON:
$('#Exemplo').DataTable( {
    "ajax": '../SuaPagina.php',
    "pageLength": 4,
    data: dataSet,
    columns: [
        { title: "Name" }
    ],
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
     "bDestroy": true //Caso recarregue os dados dinamicamente.
});


SuaPagina.php:
{
  "data": [
    [
      "Manolo"
    ],
    [
      "Manola"
    ]
  ]
}
*/

var dataSet = [
    [ "João"],
    [ "Maria"],
    [ "José"],
    [ "Pedro"],
    [ "Carlos"],
    [ "Alberto"],
    [ "Sebastião"],
    [ "Márcia"]
]

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Exemplo').DataTable( {
        "pageLength": 4,
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "Name" }
        ],
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false
    } );
} );
```

```css
#Exemplo {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">


<table id="Exemplo"></table>
```

Comment: Então como que faz para ele retornar um json com as informações? Já tentei veja na edição da pergunta

Comment: Editei minha resposta para tentar ajudá-lo. Verifique se o que é retornado da sua url_base é um tipo de **data** válido.

Comment: Sim deu certo. Só que ele retorna o erro: DataTables warning: table id=datatable-checkbox - Requested unknown parameter '' for row 0, column 1. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Comment: E tem outro erro: DataTables warning: table id=datatable-checkbox - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

Comment: Se você recarrega os dados dela dinamicamente você precisa incluir o parâmetro ->  "bDestroy": true

Comment: Já tentei de tudo cara. Ele até deu certo só que não aparece o show do total de registros. Antes sem o destroy ele aparecia

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/option/info  da uma breve lida nas opções que o datatables tem > https://datatables.net/reference/option/

Comment: Editei a pergunta veja o código e a imagem

Comment: algum erro no console?

Comment: Bom tem outra alternativa que ao invés do destroy seria chamar o método novamente $('#example').DataTable();

Comment: Não. Não aparece nada. Simplesmente ele não monta as options